# Set executable permission on script installed with Homebrew

Tags: installation, homebrew, file-permissions, linuxbrew

I wrote my first tap, so I'm still not sure how it works. I wrote this small formula:

```rb
class Konversation < Formula
  desc "Konversation is a tool to generate rich and diversified responses to the user of a voice application."
  homepage "https://github.com/rewe-digital-incubator/Konversation/"
  url "https://github.com/rewe-digital-incubator/Konversation/releases/download/1.0.0/konversation-cli.jar"
  sha256 "6123d126278faae2419f5de00411a1b67ae57e0cf2265a5d484ed6f9786baaca"

  def install
    prefix.install "#{buildpath}/konversation-cli.jar"
    File.write("#{buildpath}/konversation", "java -jar #{prefix}/konversation-cli.jar $@")
    bin.install "#{buildpath}/konversation"
    system "chmod", "+x", "#{bin}/konversation"
  end
end
```

However I cannot run my tool since the "konversation" executable has no x permission. I tried to fix that with a system chmod, however I see that my x flag is removed after the installation by brew as some kind of cleanup:

```
==> Cleaning
Fixing /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/konversation/bin/konversation permissions from 777 to 444
```

How can I set the file permissions correctly?

Please note that I don't want to host the shell script itself somewhere, since I see no advance in packaging the shell script and the jar file in another zip file for destitution.

If you want to try it yourself try this command:

```
brew install rekire/packages/konversation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell scripts need to have a shebang line, otherwise the [postinstall cleaner](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/24f5e6953db95596f0e8a89ca57fa6d918821712/Library/Homebrew/cleaner.rb#L107-L116) will set its permissions as though it were not an executable. In this specific case, I suggest:

- use `bin.write_jar_script` instead -- this will set up the correct environment for JAR scripts
- install `.jar`s to `libexec` instead of `prefix` -- to avoid polluting the prefix with unnecessary files.

[Example formula from Homebrew/homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/64155a80d5364736ee34ee49c3b71ca95163e9b5/Formula/batik.rb)